# How do I print the elements of a C++ vector in GDB?

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, vector, gdb

I want to examine the contents of a `std::vector` in GDB, how do I do it?  Let's say it's a `std::vector<int>` for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427589/inspecting-standard-container-stdmap-contents-with-gdb (the link in the answer is very interesting).

Comment: The new, better way to do this is in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492020/how-to-view-contents-of-stl-containers-using-gdb-7-x/2492341#2492341

Comment: Or [c++ - How to pretty-print STL containers in GDB? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606048/how-to-pretty-print-stl-containers-in-gdb)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To view vector std::vector myVector contents, just type in GDB:

```
(gdb) print myVector
```

This will produce an output similar to:

```
$1 = std::vector of length 3, capacity 4 = {10, 20, 30}
```

To achieve above, you need to have gdb 7 (I tested it on gdb 7.01) and some python pretty-printer. Installation process of these is described on [gdb wiki](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport).

What is more, after installing above, this works well with **Eclipse** C++ debugger GUI (and any other IDE using GDB, as I think).

Comment: This works fine as long as the vector elements are directly interpretable.  But it doesn't help if the vector contains pointers to the items of interest.

Comment: I frankly don't find the [gdb wiki](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport) page particularly readable, maybe because it's "slightly" outdated now? For instance, I had the impression that the suggested content of the `$HOME/.gdbinit` was necessary. At the moment I end up with no such file at all and `gdb` correctly showing the content of `std::vector`. However, since during my "rambling" attempts I just installed and then unistalled `cgdb`, and I already had `libstdc++5` installed, I have no idea why the pretty printing did not work while now it works.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? This does not work at all.

Answer (score 298):

With GCC 4.1.2, to print the whole of a std::vector<int> called myVector, do the following:

```
print *(myVector._M_impl._M_start)@myVector.size()
```

To print only the first N elements, do:

```
print *(myVector._M_impl._M_start)@N
```

**Explanation**

This is probably heavily dependent on your compiler version, but for GCC 4.1.2, the pointer to the internal array is:

```
myVector._M_impl._M_start
```

And the GDB command to print N elements of an array starting at pointer P is:

```
print P@N
```

Or, in a short form (for a standard .gdbinit):

```
p P@N
```

Comment: Hehe, it's something that's bugged me before, so I just looked it up this morning and added it as a memo to myself (as Jeff himself recommended).

Comment: Also if you want just a particular vector element, myVector._M_impl._M_start + n (for the nth element)

Comment: Not working for me.  `Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined`

Comment: To print a single element, e.g. the 2nd element: print (myVector._M_impl._M_start)[2]

Comment: To find the special names (`_M_impl` etc) for your compiler under GDB 7.0+, use `print /r myVector`

Comment: with GCC 5.2.0 (though I am sure it works for earlier versions), you can use `print *(&myVector[0])@myVector.size()`, which requires no specific knowledge of GCC stdlib internals.

Comment: Thanks @Eponymous !! I was wondering how to arrive at the right inner member names.

Comment: Not sure how much it helps in debugability, but in addition to this tip I also compiled with `g++ -ggdb -O0`

Answer (score 16):

put the following in ~/.gdbinit

```
define print_vector
    if $argc == 2
        set $elem = $arg0.size()
        if $arg1 >= $arg0.size()
            printf "Error, %s.size() = %d, printing last element:\n", "$arg0", $arg0.size()
            set $elem = $arg1 -1
        end
        print *($arg0._M_impl._M_start + $elem)@1
    else
        print *($arg0._M_impl._M_start)@$arg0.size()
    end
end

document print_vector
Display vector contents
Usage: print_vector VECTOR_NAME INDEX
VECTOR_NAME is the name of the vector
INDEX is an optional argument specifying the element to display
end
```

After restarting gdb (or sourcing ~/.gdbinit), show the associated help like this

```
gdb) help print_vector
Display vector contents
Usage: print_vector VECTOR_NAME INDEX
VECTOR_NAME is the name of the vector
INDEX is an optional argument specifying the element to display
```

Example usage:

```
(gdb) print_vector videoconfig_.entries 0
$32 = {{subChannelId = 177 '\261', sourceId = 0 '\000', hasH264PayloadInfo = false, bitrate = 0,     payloadType = 68 'D', maxFs = 0, maxMbps = 0, maxFps = 134, encoder = 0 '\000', temporalLayers = 0 '\000'}}
```

Comment: thank you for the code! I guess there is a typo and "print *($arg0._M_impl._M_start + $elem)@1" should be  "print *($arg0._M_impl._M_start + $arg1)@1"?
I use the following modification:
define print_vector
    if $argc == 2
        if $arg1 >= $arg0.size()-1
            printf "Error, %s.size() = %d, printing last element:\n", "$arg0", $arg0.size()-1
        end
        print *($arg0._M_impl._M_start + $arg1)@1
    else
        print *($arg0._M_impl._M_start)@$arg0.size()
    end
end

Comment: el magnifico! mochas gracias

Answer (score 14):

'Watching' STL containers while debugging is somewhat of a problem. Here are 3 different solutions I have used in the past, none of them is perfect.

1) Use GDB scripts from http://clith.com/gdb_stl_utils/ These scripts allow you to print the contents of almost all STL containers. The problem is that this does not work for nested containers like a stack of sets.

2) Visual Studio 2005 has fantastic support for watching STL containers. This works for nested containers but this is for their implementation for STL only and does not work if you are putting a STL container in a Boost container.

3) Write your own 'print' function (or method) for the specific item you want to print while debugging and use 'call' while in GDB to print the item. Note that if your print function is not being called anywhere in the code g++ will do dead code elimination and the 'print' function will not be found by GDB (you will get a message saying that the function is inlined). So compile with -fkeep-inline-functions

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, so mostly a reminder to me next time I do this search!

I have been able to use:

```
p/x *(&vec[2])@4
```

to print 4 elements (as hex) from `vec` starting at `vec[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer (Michał's) should work with recent versions of `gdb`.

On Debian 12, two packages `gdb` and `gdb-minimal` provide command `gdb`, version 13:

- `gdb` from package `gdb-minimal` could not directly print the content of `std::vector`.
- `gdb` from package `gdb` could print `std::vector`.