# How do I examine the contents of an std::vector in gdb, using the icc compiler?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, gdb, icc

I want to examine the contents of a std::vector in gdb but I don't have access to _M_impl because I'm using icc, not gcc, how do I do it? Let's say it's a std::vector for the sake of simplicity.

There is a very nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253099/how-do-i-print-the-elements-of-a-c-vector-in-gdb) but this doesn't work if I use icc, the error message is "There is no member or method named _M_impl". There appears to be a nice debug toolset [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html#STLDEREF) but it also relies on _M_impl.

Comment: +1 freaking shame that 7 years later, gdb still can't display containers in a reasonable way. not even strings...

Comment: no icc restriction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253099/how-do-i-print-the-elements-of-a-c-vector-in-gdb

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure this will work with your vector, but it worked for me.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    vec.push_back("Hello");
    vec.push_back("world");
    vec.push_back("!");
    return 0;
}
```

gdb:

```
(gdb) break source.cpp:8
(gdb) run
(gdb) p vec.begin()
$1 = {
   _M_current = 0x300340
}
(gdb) p $1._M_current->c_str()
$2 = 0x3002fc "Hello"
(gdb) p $1._M_current +1
$3 = (string *) 0x300344
(gdb) p $3->c_str()
$4 = 0x30032c "world"
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally when I deal with the container classes in a debugger, I build a reference to the element, as a local variable, so it is easy to see in the debugger, without mucking about in the container implementation.

Here is a contrived example.

```
vector<WeirdStructure>  myWeird;

/* push back a lot of stuff into the vector */ 

size_t z;
for (z = 0; z < myWeird.size(); z++)
{
    WeirdStructure& weird = myWeird[z];

    /* at this point weird is directly observable by the debugger */ 

    /* your code to manipulate weird goes here */  
}
```

That is the idiom I use.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::vector` template [guarantees the data is stored contiguously](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/).  If you take the address of the front element (say, `&v[0]`, for instance), you can access any other element in the vector through a C-style array.  That doesn't require you to have the source code of the STL available to your debugger.

---

After messing with this some, it appears that `v.front()` and `v.begin()` are likely inlined and GDB isn't finding them.  I'll keep looking, but personally I would simply add the line `int* i = &v[0]` to the source file, and then use GDB commands on `i` while debugging.  Note that the compiler is free to remove that dead code.  You may need to output the value of `i` to avoid that, or simply not crank up optimizations.

Comment: how do I access the first element? myvector[0] doesn't work in gdb..?

Comment: thanks for your help. gdb doesn't let me call myvector.front() on the print line? --> Couldn't find method std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::front

Comment: Sorry, last time I tried to call member functions in gdb I had to pass in the name-mangled name (that is, the symbol that actually appears in the binary).  I'm sure they fixed it by now.  &v[0] is more common to see than &(v.front()), so I've changed the answer to use that.

Comment: thanks again for your help. This is the first thing I tried, the [] operator also doesn't work.
>print nactive_serverByTB[0]
One of the arguments you tried to pass to operator[] could not be converted to what the function wants.

Comment: Thanks. The icc compiled version (v9.1) doesn't seem to allow this. Strange.