# Inspecting standard container (std::map) contents with gdb

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, gdb

Supposing to have something like this:

```
#include <map>
int main(){
    std::map<int,int> m;
    m[1] = 2;
    m[2] = 4;
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to be able to inspect the contents of the map running the program from gdb.
If I try using the subscript operator I get:

```
(gdb) p m[1]
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.
```

Using the find method does not yield better results:

```
(gdb) p m.find(1)
Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: To print all elements without truncating large maps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743215/having-gdb-print-a-big-stdmap-fully-while-debugging A more "Cannot evaluate function maybe inlined" focused: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633787/c-stl-gdb-cannot-evaluate-function-maybe-inlined

Comment: General question: [c++ - How to pretty-print STL containers in GDB? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606048/how-to-pretty-print-stl-containers-in-gdb)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think there isn't, at least not if your source is optimized etc. However, there are some macros for gdb that can inspect STL containers for you:

http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2008-02/msg00064.html

However, I don't use this, so YMMV

Comment: Thanks for the link; the only thing is that macros are dependent from the stl libraries version, which I'd prefer to avoid. +1

Comment: Its also a bit frustrating that commands like "plist foo std::string" give syntax errors.  It appears that the value_type can't contain any punctuation.

Comment: I haven't tried, but if this works the same as the rest of GDB, enclosing the name with punctuated name in single quotes should do it.

Comment: Note: the std::map functionality in these scripts assumes 32-bit pointer types.  For 64-bit machines, replace "+ 4" to "+ 8" everywhere in the file.

Comment: pvector isn't defined in my gdb (version 7.5.91.20130417-cvs-ubuntu).

Answer (score 114):

The existing answers to this question are **very** out of date. With a recent GCC and GDB it Just Works<sup>TM</sup> thanks to the built-in Python support in GDB 7.x and the libstdc++ pretty printers that come with GCC.

For the OP's example I get:

```
(gdb) print m
$1 = std::map with 2 elements = {[1] = 2, [2] = 4}
```

If it doesn't work automatically for you see the first bullet point on the [STL Support](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport) page of the GDB wiki.

You can write Python pretty printers for your own types too, see [Pretty Printing](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html#Pretty-Printing) in the GDB manual.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... actually the question itself is rather out of date by now :)

Comment: Yes, but other questions are getting closed as duplicates of it, so I wanted it to have recent information.

Comment: I am using GDB 7.2 and the above works ... if you have a small collection. I still haven't found any way to print say element 1543 from a 4K vector, other than resorting to using internal structures of the STL implementation.

Comment: @pavon, did you try `print vec[1543]`? that works perfectly for me with GDB 7.6

Comment: Yes, in GDB 7.2 and the icpc compiler I get the error `Could not find operator[]`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't "Just Work" in all the distros. It isn't installed by default in Ubuntu 13.10 and there are [problems when you try to install it manually](http://askubuntu.com/questions/403143/setting-up-gdb-pretty-printing-in-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: That shows the entire map. The OP asked how to show a specific element of the map.

Comment: @user570500, that's one way to interpret it. The OP asks "I would like to be able to inspect the contents of the map running the program from gdb. [...] Is there a way to accomplish this?" My answer shows a way to inspect the contents.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Which distro are you using where it just works?

Comment: @razeh, Fedora, RHEL (and RHEL clones). There's a fix in progress to make the printers also work on distros where GDB is linked to Python 3

Comment: The upstream GCC code has been fixed to work with Python3, so it should work in Ubuntu and Debian soon

Comment: This needs a definition of "recent" .... it's not very useful for the people stuck on "not recent" if they don't know what they need to update to

Comment: @UKMonkey given that the answer is over five years old, "something less than six years old" would be a fairly obvious (and conservative) guess. It looks like the libstdc++ printers were added for GCC 4.5.0 which was released in 2010. Some distros backported them to GCC 4.4, and maybe earlier.

Comment: @JonathanWakely :) I don't disagree... but, the gdb I'm stuck with is "really quite old" (excess of 8 years) which is why I made my comment and it doesn't seem to Just work (tm).

Sad times - more googling required I guess!

Comment: @UKMonkey if you're asking about GDB, the answer already says GDB 7.x (and has done since 2013).

Comment: And the "STL Support" link I gave in the answer says "GDB 7.0 will include support for writing pretty-printers in Python."

Comment: Is it possible to print the implementation/body of a `std::function` by GDB?

Comment: @skytree that should really be a separate question, or on the gcc-help mailing list, not as a comment on a question about std::map. The answer is no, but somebody could write a printer for it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thank you. Could you please offer me a reference link about that printer or just related posts?

Answer (score 25):

There's always the obvious:  Define your own test-function...  Call it from gdb.  E.g.:

```
#define SHOW(X) cout << # X " = " << (X) << endl

void testPrint( map<int,int> & m, int i )
{
  SHOW( m[i] );
  SHOW( m.find(i)->first );
}

int
main()
{
    std::map<int,int> m;
    m[1] = 2;
    m[2] = 4;
    return 0;  // Line 15.
}
```

And:

```
....
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400e08: file foo.C, line 15.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/z/qD 

Breakpoint 1, main () at qD.C:15
(gdb) call testPrint( m, 2)
m[i] = 4
(*m.find(i)).first = 2
(gdb)
```

Comment: as long as the process is running. not so useful for core-dumps.

Comment: This is useful advice debug GDB in general, not just with STL.  I keep a whole library of gdb helper functions for lots of hard-to-retrieve data, e.g. write_cuda_array_as_image().  Note that some compilers will strip out any functions that aren't called, so I place a call to each helper function after my main's "return 0;".  Also declaring them with extern "C" makes calling them from gdb easier.

Comment: @KyleSimek gcc also supports ` __attribute__((used))` so the linker won't toss the symbol if unused

Answer (score 21):

The `stl-views.gdb` used to be the best answer there was, but not anymore.

This isn't integrated into the mainline `GDB` yet, but here is what you get using the 'archer-tromey-python' [branch](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProjectArcher):

```
(gdb) list
1   #include <map>
2   int main(){
3       std::map<int,int> m;
4       m[1] = 2;
5       m[2] = 4;
6       return 0;
7   }
(gdb) break 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048274: file map.cc, line 6.
(gdb) run

Breakpoint 1, main () at map.cc:6
6       return 0;
(gdb) print m
$1 = std::map with 2 elements = {
  [1] = 2,
  [2] = 4
}
(gdb) quit
```

Answer (score 13):

Try De-Referencing STL Containers:  on this page: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html

Comment: These look to be the business!

Comment: They're actually the same macros as in the previous answer :) I'm afraid there's no simpler solution.

Comment: What is the command? You managed to run us off-site with copious amounts of irrelevant information. I'm not interested in "How to start GDB" and the others.

Answer (score 3):

The answers above are working and fine. In case you are using stl-views.gdb, here is the proper way of viewing the maps and elements inside it.
Let your map is as follows :
    `std::map<char, int> myMap;`

```
(gdb) pmap myMap char int
```

i.e. `pmap <variable_name> <left_element_type> <right_element_type>` to see the elements in the map.

Hope that helps.

Comment: `stl-views` is outdated, gdb has pretty print after 7.0. The instruction [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug.html#debug.gdb)

Answer (score -1):

You can get around the second problem (`Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined`) by making sure that your compiler uses DWARF-2 (or 3 or 4) debugging information when you compile your program. DWARF-2 includes inlining information, so you should be able to use either of the methods you described to access elements of your `std::map` container.

To compile with DWARF-2 debug info, add the `-gdwarf-2` flag to your compile command.

Comment: Um, knowing where a function has been inlined does not make it possible for GDB to evaluate calls to that function; GDB really needs access to an out-of-line copy of the function!