# Debugging Best Practices for C++ STL/Boost with gdb

Tags: c++, stl, boost, gdb

Debugging with gdb, any c++ code that uses STL/boost is still a nightmare. Anyone who has used gdb with STL knows this. For example, see sample runs of some debugging sessions in code [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html#STLDEREF).

I am trying to reduce the pain by collecting tips. Can you please comment on the tips I have collected below (particularly which ones you have been using and any changes you would recommend on them) - I have listed the tips is decreasing order of technicality.

- Is anyone using ["Stanford GDB STL utils"](http://www.stanford.edu/~afn/gdb_stl_utils/) and ["UCF GDB utils"](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/src/dbinit_stl_views-1.01.txt)? Is there some such utils for boost data structures? The utils above do not seem to be usable recursively, for example for printing vector of a boost::shared_ptr in a legible manner within one command.
- Write your .gdbinit file. Include, for example, C++ related beautifiers, listed at the bottom of UCF GDB utils.
- Use checked/debug STL/Boost library, such as STLport.
- Use logging (for example as described [here](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/201804215))

*Update*: GDB has a [new C++ branch](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProjectArcher).

Comment: Asked and answered, but gdb 7 has much better support for STL containers - our out-of-the-box installation includes support for printing them like "$4 = std::vector of length 4, capacity 4 = {0, 2, 4, 888}".  I haven't seen what it does with complex types or other containers, but it seems like a huge improvement.  See [this page](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport) for more details...

Comment: @RobI Thanks! However, much to my agony I found the python-based support still lacking when I use boost pointer containers, which I do quite often. GDB simply keeps complaining and not printing the contents.

Comment: See also: [c++ - How to pretty-print STL containers in GDB? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606048/how-to-pretty-print-stl-containers-in-gdb)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe not the sort of "tip" you were looking for, but I have to say that my experience after a few years of moving from C++ & STL to C++ & boost & STL is that I now spend a *lot* less time in GDB than I used to.  I put this down to a number of things:

- boost smart pointers (particularly "shared pointer", and the pointer containers when performance is needed).  I can't remember the last time I had to write an explicit delete (delete is the "goto" of C++ IMHO).  There goes a lot of GDB time tracking down invalid and leaking pointers.
- boost is full of proven code for things you'd probably hack together an inferior version of otherwise.  e.g `boost::bimap` is great for the common pattern of LRU caching logic.  There goes another heap of GDB time.
- Adopting unittesting.  `boost::test`'s AUTO macros mean it's an absolute doddle to set up test cases ([easier than CppUnit](http://gamesfromwithin.com/?p=29)).  This catches lots of stuff long before it gets built into anything you'd have to attach a debugger to.
- Related to that, tools like `boost::bind` make it easier to design-for-test.  e.g algorithms can be more generic and less tied up with the types they operate on; this makes plugging them into test shims/proxies/mock objects etc easier (that and the fact that exposure to boost's template-tasticness will encourage you to "dare to template" things you'd never have considered before, yielding similar testing benefits).
- `boost::array`.  "C array" performance, with range checking in debug builds.
- boost is full of great code you can't help but learn from

Comment: > boost is full of great code you can't help but learn from

I sure agree, but for beginners it is a huge hill to climb. They are afraid when they see half-page long compiler error messages.

Comment: Very true!   A useful tip is to paste them into an editor and search-and-replace e.g std::basic_string<yadda yadda yadda> with STRING and reduce the things down to something comprehensible (typically it's the "top level" you're interested in, not the detail).

Comment: If you can use C++11, notice that the boost smart pointers are now part of the standard library in C++11

Answer (score 5):

You might look at:

[Inspecting standard container (std::map) contents with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427589/inspecting-stdmap-contents-with-gdb)

Comment: And in particular see reference to the Archer project (http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProjectArcher) which I just added there.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest and most option is to use logging (well I actually use debug prints, but I think that's not a point). The biggest advantage is that you can inspect any type of data, many times per program execution and then search it with a text editor to look for interesting data. Note that this is very fast. The disadvantage is obvious, you must preselect the data which you want to log and places where to log. However, that is not such a serious issue, because you usually know where in the code bad things are happening (and if not, you just add sanity checks here and there and then, you will know).

Checked/debug libraries are good, but they are better as a testing tool (eg. run it and see if I'm doing anything wrong), and not as good at debugging a specific issue. They can't detect a flaw in user code.

Otherwise, I use plain GDB. It is not that bad as it sounds, although it might be if you are scared by "`print x`" printing a screenful of junk. But, if you have debugging information, things like printing a member of a `std::vector` work and if anything fails, you still can inspect the raw memory by the `x` command. But if I know what I'm looking for, I use option 1 - logging.

Note that the "difficult to inspect" structures are not only STL/Boost, but also from other libraries, like Qt/KDE.