# configuring gdb to change the display of objects

Tags: c++, object, gdb

In GDB, objects typically display with lots of tripe due to included template objects.
There's a lot of useless std::char_traits ...

Is there a way to filter this stuff out?  Basically, I'd like to know if I can configure .gdbinit to display the text only for a std::string, and perhaps the first few elements for a vector.

Alternatively, is there some sort of macro I can write to let me print out just a particular field of an object instead of writing by hand

For a string, I can write:

```
p s.c_str()
```

but I'll get a seg fault if it's NULL.
I'd like enough logic to ignore that but don't know that gdb has any facility for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are such things about! It's a bit limited but you can do it.

Look [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport) and also [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432567/debugging-best-practices-for-c-stl-boost-with-gdb)

Comment: What is limited? GDB supports python output routines from version 7.0. You can also write pretty printers for your own classes if you want, it's actually very simple.