# How to get value of a data member in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

Hi I am currently debugging my code base in linux machine through GDB. I am currently facing an issue in getting value of a data member from object ptr of a class. To print the location for object ptr we can use either "p" (print) or "display" command.

For Eg: I have class like this

```
class abc
{
    string a;
};
```

So in my code if I am using a pointer for class abc, then

```
abc* objPtr = new abc();
```

so after breaking at above line i will get objPtr and now I want to check value of datamember a (abc::a) value. how I could do that?

```
(gdb) p objPtr
$2 = {px = 0x3ba6430690, pn = {pi_ = 0x3ba6430698}}
```

Moreover Is there a different way to check a data member which is a list / vector ?

Comment: yeah I have compiled it with -g option\

Comment: Regarding your list/vector question, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427589/inspecting-standard-container-stdmap-contents-with-gdb

Comment: That gdb output looks like a boost::shared_ptr<abc> not abc*, so try print *objPtr->px or print objPtr->px->a

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer.

```
$p/a objPtr->datamember->[if datamember also has some data member then we can call it in recurcion / can also call member function].
```

for list/vector we could refer to  http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2008-02/msg00064/stl-views.gdb.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$ p abc->c_str()
```

Comment: You missed the `a` and used the type instead of the instance: `objPtr->a.c_str();`

Comment: what if I want to check a list which is datamember for class abc?

Comment: Note: calling functions only work while attached to a process, not while inspecting a core (it's a limitation to keep in mind).

Answer (score 0):

```
p objPtr->a
```

will print the data member type and value of variable `a`