# Understanding gdb output

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I am trying to use the push_back function for a vector in c++.
I am getting a seg fault and when I ran the gdb to find the exact reason.

I get the following.

```
$1={px = 0xbfffe9c4, pn = { pi_ = 0x8049c0b}}
```

I do not have much experience with gdb and cannot find anything related to this specific issue online.

Comment: You get that when you do what, specifically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get value of a data member in gdb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814170/how-to-get-value-of-a-data-member-in-gdb)

Answer (score 3):

My magic ball tells me you crashed while dereferencing a `shared_ptr`. Follow the `px` member, since that is the actual pointer value of interest to you. For example, you can try:

```
print $1.px
```

and if the pointer points to a valid memory area:

```
print *$1.px
```

The `gdb` debugger will provide you with a lot of information, but some of the more useful things: `backtrace`, `up`, `down`, `info locals`, and if you are multi-threaded, `thread apply all backtrace`. If you are debugging live, then of course you will need `breakpoint`, `next`, `step` and `continue`. You should be able to use `gdb`'s help for more information, and the [`gdb` manual](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/documentation/) is readily available online.