# How can I view the contents of an std::map in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, debugging, eclipse-cdt, watch

I'm trying to view the contents on an std::map using Eclipse CDT, but all I seem to see is a(n infinite?) tree of red-and-black tree nodes.

1. Where's the actual data?
2. How come CDT doesn't offer some pretty-printed view of the contents of the map?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to what extent Eclipse CDT supports this by default right now, but recent versions of GDB can show you a human-friendly visualization of STL containers, including `std::map`.  You need GCC version 7 or later and then you can say `print the_map_name` and it will show you something like this:

```
std::map with 2 elements = {[1] = 2, [2] = 4}
```

For more details on that, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15329434/4323

And for some tips on making it work in Eclipse: [How to enable gdb pretty printing for C++ STL objects in Eclipse CDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985414/enable-pretty-printing-for-gdb-in-eclipse-cdt)

Comment: I went there, saw the explanation, it didn't work on my system (which apparently already has some `.gdbinit` code for pretty-printing.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a map iterator iter, just type in the Expressions dialog of Eclipse one of these:

```
iter->first
iter->second
```

When you just put iter in the watch window, this will not show the first and second... maybe a bug in Eclipse.
(sorry for late reply)

Comment: That's not what I asked. I don't have an iterator, I have a map, and I want to see all of its data. Please remove this answer.