# What debugger tools do you use to look at contents of a STL container (on linux)

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, gdb, unix

I use gdb (actually DDD), and getting an element out of container is impossible. So I typically end up rolling my own loop for debugging purposes...

What do you do?

Answer (score 3):

[Qt Creator](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/developer-tools) is [capable of visualizing](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/06/22/peek-and-poke/) both Qt containers and STL containers.

There's ongoing [work](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProjectArcher) to get [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to support [pretty printing](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=524) on its own.  So far it hasn't made it into any official releases yet, but Fedora 11 [shipped it already](http://www.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Archer).

Answer (score 2):

Here's some previous answers, for [vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253099/how-do-i-print-the-elements-of-a-c-vector-in-gdb) and for [maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427589/inspecting-standard-container-stdmap-contents-with-gdb) - especially note the first answer in the maps question.