# How to watch values of vector in Kdevelop debugger?

Tags: kdevelop

I know that with `VisualStudio`, there are more possibilities to view the values in a `std::vector v`, like `v._first, 100` -> displays the first 100 elements, or changing some log file. Is there a way to do this in `KDevelop` under `Ubuntu 14.04`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GDB plugin allows you to enter plain GDB commands (see the bottom line edit in the GDB tool view).

Then it just boils down to printing the vector, see here for more information and options: [How do I print the elements of a C++ vector in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253099/how-do-i-print-the-elements-of-a-c-vector-in-gdb)