# How can I print the elements of a C++ vector in GDB on OSX 10.9?

Tags: c++, macos, vector, gdb

I have read all the answers in [How do I print the elements of a C++ vector in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253099/how-do-i-print-the-elements-of-a-c-vector-in-gdb). But none of them can solve my problem on OSX 10.9, because nearly all of them are based on the fact that `_M_impl` is a member of `vector`, which is not the case on Mac.

Here is the result when I tried to write `~/.gdbinit` according to [this link](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html#STLDEREF)

```
(gdb) pvector palin
There is no member or method named _M_impl.
```

I tried to read the source code of vector in `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/debug/vector` (is this the right file ???), but I found it confusing. I think it is a little beyond my competence.

How can I print the elements of a C++ vector in GDB on OSX 10.9?

Comment: I dunno anything about OSX, but if you just inspect the vector, what members does it give you? One of them is going to be the equivalent of `_M_impl` - it's just going to be named something different.

Comment: @Barry I hope so too. But there's no such element there, although here's an element `_M_impl` in `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/vector`.

Comment: There are two popular standard library implementations, libstdc++ (from GCC) and libc++ (from the LLVM/clang project). Chances are, you are on libc++. Gdb comes with Python pretty-printers that work with libstdc++, but there seems to be no support for libc++. You may have to create a version of pretty-printers for libc++ (requires moderately advanced wizardry) or switch your development to libc++ (requires easy lightweight wizardry, but not a universal solution).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I turn to `lldb`, the default debug tool on Mac OSX.

I can print any container now. Thank god.