# Debugging c++ gdb stl in a header file (dumping a vector)

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

I am trying to dump the values inside of vectors using gdb and stl but the vectors are in an #included header.h file and don't appear in debugging.

How do you dump the value inside of a vector in a header file?

code:

```
#cat buymngr.h 
void buymngr(){
        //vector defs
        vector<std::string> buydat;
        vector<std::string> markdat;
        vector<std::string> pricedat;
        vector<std::string> qworkcoin;
        buydat = getmyData();
        markdat = getmarketbuyData();
        cout << "Bork!" << endl;
        if(buydat[2] == std::string("Buy")){
                cout << "Bork2!" << endl;
                for(int b = 2; b < buydat.size(); b+=7){
                        int y = 3;  y+=7;
                        if ( buydat[b] == "Buy" ) {
                                pricedat.push_back(buydat[b+1]);
                //I need to dump these 2 vectors
                                qworkcoin.push_back(buydat[y+1]);
                        }
        }
    }


#cat main.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

#include "getmyData.h"
#include "getmarketsellData.h"
#include "getmarketbuyData.h"
#include "buymngr.h"
#include "sellmngr.h"

using namespace std;

//Le Main
int main(void)
{
        buymngr();
        sellmngr();
}
```

debug:

```
gdb> r
Starting program: /home/main
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
I got my own data
I just got market buy data
Bork!
Bork2!

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_______________________________________________________________________________
     eax:0000000A ebx:0060A1B0  ecx:0060A1B0  edx:0060A2E8     eflags:00010206
     esi:0060A2E8 edi:0060A1B0  esp:FFFFBD90  ebp:FFFFBDF0     eip:Error while running hook_stop:
Value can't be converted to integer.
0x00007ffff7b9355b in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.3/libstdc++.so.6
gdb> l
Line number 30 out of range; masterMain.cpp has 29 lines.
gdb> ll
Undefined command: "ll".  Try "help".
gdb> #include "buymngr.h"
gdb> include "buymngr.h"
Undefined command: "include".  Try "help".
gdb> l
Line number 30 out of range; masterMain.cpp has 29 lines.
gdb> p
```

Comment: In particular, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2123260/862351) answer tells you how to setup gdb for pretty printing.

Comment: the question is about gdb you fool!  Wrong post buddie!