# GDB : print contents of vector

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc

I'm using gcc 4.8.2 and gdb 7.7.1.
I am stepping through a C++ program and I want to print the contents of a vector.
I've tried applying the solution mentionned here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/253101/91607

But I end up getting an error : "Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined"

How do I resolve this ? it's a pain...

I'm trying to step through this bitcoin function('signrawtransaction') : https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/rpcrawtransaction.cpp#L487

Comment: What is the syntax of the gdb command you have tried?

Comment: How did you compile? What versions of gcc/gdb are you using? Recent versions come with python scripts that should print the vector by default, without any specific command.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, I'm using gcc 4.8.2 and gdb 7.7.1

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you have tried to use `vector::size` in your gdb command and that function could have been inlined. Try to use a fixed size instead just to check if it solves your problem.

Or use `-fno-default-inline` and `-fno-inline` g++ flags to disable inlining and test again.

P.S. I am just guessing. It is difficult to be of more help without actually looking at your gdb command and the code itself.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it did not help. the code I'm debugging is the 'signrawtransaction' from bitcoin : https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/rpcrawtransaction.cpp#L487