# gdb: how do you get the max value of a std::vector<float>?

Tags: c++, vector, gdb

I am debugging some C++ code and I have a really large `std::vector<floating_point_type>` (`float` or `double`). In C++ code when I want the max value of the `std::vector` I can just use `std::max_element()`. So in `gdb` I tried to use the same code, but I got an error.

In `gdb` I used `call std::max_element(x)` and got an error message `No symbol "max_element" in namespace "std".`

**Is there any way to get the max value of a vector in `gdb`?**

I would also appreciate an explanation for why my attempt at using `std::max_element` was not working (perhaps `std::max_element` a header-only or inline function).

Comment: `std::max_element()` is a template function so I am afraid gdb is not clever enough to instantiate it on the fly.

Comment: Gdb lets you write functions (in it's own scripting language or python) that you can call to display your vector: they can trivially iterate the elements to find a maximum then display that.  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25499805/410767) should help you get started.

Comment: @TonyDelroy i purposely wrote the question open ended because i was thinking of writing my own for loop to find the max element. your comment could easily be a solution (whether in gdb language or python language.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`std::max_element` is a function template, not a function. You are asking GDB to do template argument deduction and the whole shebang involved with calling a template function without specifying arguments. It can't do that, naturally, it's not a full fledged compiler.

As far as I know any solution, from the simplest to the most complex, will require of you to modify your source in such a way that `std::max_element` is instantiated for the iterator types of your vector. So you may as well add "debug only" code that computes the maximum element and stores it into a local variable.

Comment: for most cases, i think compiling/instantiating a "debug only" function is the most straight forward solution to get access to `std::max_element` from `gdb`. for some minority cases, i think @n.m. has a good solution (although for my eyes @n.m.'s looks difficult/very-complex (his solution probably only seems difficult to me because I'm a newbie at C++ with only 17+ years experience)).

Comment: [here is some good example code that someone created after your solution to demonstrate what you are describing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912371/52074).

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith - Well. To be fair, n.m.'s solution is "the most complex solution" I had in mind. It just brilliantly manages to avoid restarting the debugging session.

Answer (score 6):

```
(gdb) p std::max⭾⭾⭾
```

(No response from gdb)

```
 (gdb) p std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end())
 No symbol "max_element" in namespace "std".
```

Here is how to call an uninstantiated function template from `gdb` without breaking your session and recompiling your program.

1. Open an editor and create a C++ source file with an explicit instantiation  of the needed function. For example:

   ```
   // /tmp/tmpsource.cpp
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <vector>
   using T = std::vector<int>::iterator;
   template T std::max_element<T>(T, T);
   ```

   This can probably be automated somehow with a shell script. Give it a name of a function and template arguments, and it will generate you a complete buildable C++ source. Probably not worth the trouble though.
2. Build a shared library/DLL from the source.

   ```
   g++ -fPIC -shared -ggdb -O0 -o /tmp/libtmpsource.so /tmp/tmpsource.cpp
   ```
3. Load the library in your debugging session.

   ```
   load /tmp/libtmpsource.so
   # if this doesn't work
   p dlopen("/tmp/libtmpsource.so", 2)
   # or perhaps even
   p LoadLibraryA("c:/temp/libtmpsource.so")
   ```
4. Let's try the function now.

   ```
   (gdb) p std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end())
   No symbol "max_element" in namespace "std".
   ```
5. What? No worries, everything is under control. gdb is not a C++ compiler and it cannot do the template deduction thing. You need to specify your `<...>` yourself. Fortunately, autocompletion works (sometimes).

   ```
   (gdb) p std::max⭾
   (gdb) p std::max_element<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, 
    std::allocator<int> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, 
    std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, 
    std::allocator<int> > >)
   ```

Comment: Guess I was wrong. There is a sufficiently complex solution that doesn't involve changing the debugging sessions' source code :D +1

Comment: **starts reading... gets to part about "just open an editor, compile, then go to gdb and load the shared object library. laughs out loud**

Comment: **starts to read section on you need to specify the template parameters because gdb can not deduct... reads the horrifyingly long template parameters. laughs out loud.**

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith yes they are horribly long but at least gdb tab-completes them for you.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Would you still be laughing if you discovered that you have to leave gdb and recompile after a 100+ hours session of chasing an elusive bug?

Comment: @n.m. hm. hm. Sobering statement.

Answer (score 3):

As std::max_elemente is a function template, you can not use it directly in gdb.
What you can do, create a wrapper over it.

```
float my_max_element(std::vector<float>& vec) 
{
    return *(std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

Now you can call my_max_element in gdb.